# Magento 2: Passing browser information to payment gateway interface

Tags: magento2

I am implementing SCA (3dSecureV2) and part of the request is that I need to pass some variables via PHP to the gateway.

However, what is the best way of getting these front end (browser) settings to the php code in my controller?

Is there an example in M2 already?

```
    $this->browserData = new BrowserData();
    $this->browserData->colorDepth = ColorDepth::TWENTY_FOUR_BITS;
    $this->browserData->javaEnabled = true;
    $this->browserData->language = 'en';
    $this->browserData->screenHeight = 1080;
    $this->browserData->screenWidth = 1920;
    $this->browserData->challengWindowSize = ChallengeWindowSize::WINDOWED_600X400;
    $this->browserData->timeZone = '0';
```